# MATLAB UITABLE AND FORMAT OPTIONS

Tags: matlab

I have followed many posts about format of numbers in Matlab. Now I have set up Matlab uitable in such a way that one can fill the table cell by cell. I want the first column to maintain numbers up to say 12 digits, so I set the format to longG. Matlab uitable is refusing to accept my format and the frustrating part is, in the command window all digits are shown even up to 15 digits with format longG option. This is the sample;

```
colNam={'W','X','Y','Z'};

t=uitable('ColumnName',colNam,'Data',zeros(4),'ColumnEditable',...
    [true true true true],'ColumnWidth',{150,'auto'},...
    'ColumnFormat',{'numeric'});
set(t,'ColumnFormat',{'longG'});
```

I know of sprintf and fprintf as has been explained elsewhere. But please what we are refusing to realize is that, these change the class of the number from double to char. What if you want to set up the table so that it increases by 1 dynamically (credits to thewaywewalk)? We can't add double to char for this purpose. Please this is frustrating. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such ColumnFormat property called "longG", where dis you see that ?
You have the possibility of manipulating the Java part of the Uitable in order to really display numeric values... but I think the best (and easiest) way is to use char.

If you want to increase the values, just convert it first to numeric, increase, then convert it back.

Comment: Oh yes, I did that and it worked. I am grateful. I have posted my attempt as well but without the dynamic increase in value. I just got the table data and converted to cell array of strings and put it back into another table. Thank you, John.

Answer (score 0):

Based on John's suggestion, I put up this code and I could set the table to accept any number of digits.

```
f=figure;
dat=[101100220001;101100220002;101100220003;101100220004;101100220005];
colNam={'W'};

t=uitable('ColumnName',colNam,'Data',dat,'ColumnEditable',...
    [true],'ColumnWidth',{150},'pos',[5 250 200 120]);

newdat=get(t,'Data');
newdat=strtrim(cellstr(num2str(newdat))); %Convert data to cell array of strings
tt=uitable('ColumnName',colNam,'Data',newdat,'pos',[300 250 200 120]);
```

Comment: I could have converted to strings straight from 'dat' matrix. I only wanted to be sure my data will appear as exponents in the uitable, get the data and change the format. Thanks.